# How do I script my ROBLOX ClickDetector only allow click input once, so the script only plays once and cannot be spammed?

Tags: roblox

Please help me edit my script to make it so when the block/part is clicked it will only execute the script once? I don't want to be able to click the block/part multiple times and the script play out per click. It should only move as far as it's stated ONCE when the block/part is clicked.

My script:

[image]

Comment: Provide the code as `code block`, don't take the screenshot or link because it's may be broken and hard for others to test

Comment: `local movingpart = game.Workspace.MovingPart

game.Workspace.ClickDetectorEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()

 for i = 1,20 do
 movingpart.CFrame = CFrame.new(movingpart.Position + Vector3.new(.5,0,0))
 wait()
end
 for i= 1,20 do
 movingpart.CFrame = CFrame.new(movingpart.Position + Vector3.new(0,0,.5))
 wait()
end
end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of dealing with this is to set a boolean from false to true when it has been clicked once, and check at the top of the function whether that boolean is true or false before proceeding.

```lua
local debounce = false
function foo()
   if not debounce then
      debounce = true
      print("Hi!")
   end
end

foo() -- Will print "Hi!"
foo() -- Will not print anything
```

You can apply the same logic to your script. 
If you are certain you only want this to happen once, you can alternatively disconnect your OnServerEvent-event once it runs. An event connection can be stored as a variable and later :Disconnect()-ed, similar to how you :Connect().

```lua
local myConnection
myConnection = myEvent:Connect(function()
   myConnection:Disconnect()
   print("Hello!")
end)
myEvent:Fire() -- Prints "Hello!"
myEvent:Fire() -- Does nothing, because it is no longer connected/listening for input.
```

Answer (score 0):

If its like a single player game just try :destroy()
try `game.Workspace.ClickDetectorEvent:Destroy()` hope this helps